# javascript es6 callback running first

Tags: callback, ecmascript-6

I've built the following event listener which will run the function isValidEmail, passing in a callback function NotInDatabase() which is scheduled to only run after an ajax call is complete. It appears though that NotInDatabase() runs immediately. Any idea why this would be happening?

Event listener:

```
const bindEvents = (form, inputSelector, errorSelector) => {
   const emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
   emailInput.addEventListener('blur', function(){
     const emailValue = emailInput.value
     isValidEmail('http://localhost:3001/user/email/'+emailValue,'data_placeholder', NotInDatabase())
   });
}
```

isValidEmail with callback:

```
const isValidEmail = (url, data, success) => {
  const xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xhr.open('POST', url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) {
      success(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
xhr.send(data);
return xhr;
}
```

Comment: https://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
isValidEmail('http://localhost:3001/user/email/'+emailValue,'data_placeholder', NotInDatabase())
```

you do not pass `NotInDatabase` function as a callback into `isValidEmail`, but pass what it returns because `NotInDatabase()` is a function call.

Remove `()` to solve your problem

Comment: Or in other words, instead of passing the callback, you're calling it then passing the return.